# Bootstrap modal not showing (SmartAdmin)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is probably some easy mistake, but I can't get bootstrap modal til show up.

My modal is defined like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mainModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="mainModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">  
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

My trigger:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="modPerson/ajax/modal-content/personForm.php?id={{ siteInfo.innloggaId }}" data-target="#mainModal" class="jarvismetro-tile big-cubes bg-color-pinkDark"> <span class="iconbox"> <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i> <span>Min Info </span> </span> </a>
```

JQuery and Bootstrap is loaded, but it looks like none of the data-actions are triggered. The browser just goes to the href in the A tag.

I'm trying to get this to work within the SmartAdmin bootstrap template.

Comment: You do have a huge space between `aria-` and `labelledby`.

Comment: `data-toggle="modal"` with an `href` or `data-remote` is deprecated since Bootstrap v3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

`SmartAdmin` has its own modal you have to use that. `Bootstrap` modal will not work there